# Jenkins: How to generate a number sequence for all builds

Tags: jenkins, numbers, sequence, jenkins-pipeline

we are building app for hockeyapp from different branches using the multibranch pipeline. All of the build are being uploaded to HockeyApp using the same app. Since in a multibranch pipeline all jobs have their own build number sequence, we can not use this to generate the app build number.

We do need a sequence that is generated for all jobs on our jenkins counting up.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: Does it have to be sequential, could you not use the HASH of the repo ?

Comment: actually no. Hockey app supports numerical build numbers only and they need to be ascending

Comment: You could use a script to process a prime number derivative of the EPOCH time. like https://github.com/kuro68k/timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little late, but just wanted to post how we solved. We simply set up a service endpoint on Jenkins that generates unique number and use that in the job to get a number.